# Collection of connected sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be any space. The Union of family of connected subsets such for each two connected subsets have at least one point in common is also connected.

My attempted

I want to use this definition: the space $X$ is connected if every continuous function from X to $\{0,1\}$ is constant, where $\{0,1\}$ is given the discrete topology.

Now, let $Y=\cup A_ k$ (where $k\in{\mathbb{R}}$), and let  $g: Y \to \{0,1\}$ be continuous. My goal is to show that $g$ is constant. Since $A_k$ is connected for each $k$, then $g|_{A_k}$ is constant. Since the intersection of any two sets are not empty.

Here is my question

It seems to me that $g$ is constant. Consequence, $Y$ it's connected. However , I could not explain why $g$ is constant?

Any help will appreciated

Comment: Let say if $f|_{A_k} = 1$ and $f|_{A_l} = 0$, is that possible?

Comment: Who says your collection of connected sets can be indexed by $\mathbb{R}$? (A general index set $I$ would suffice).

Comment: To actually prove the claim, note that you haven't yet used the fact that each pair of connected sets have at least one point in common yet. How does that help you show that $g$ is constant?

Answer (score 1):

Pick $x,y$ in the union. $x$ is in some $A_{\lambda_1}$ and $y$ in some $A_{\lambda_2}$ (OBS: why did you assume the indexing on $\mathbb{R}$?).

By the hypothesis, there is $z$ in $ A_{\lambda_1} \cap A_{\lambda_2}$. Since $g$ is constant in every restriction, it follows that $g(x)=g(z)=g(y)$. Since $x,y$ are arbitrary, the result follows.